# Getting Facebook to return User Data to Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a chrome extension that needs to allow user authentication through facebook. I've been following the ["manual login flow"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1) since the facebook Javascript SDK doesn't work in extensions.  Thus far, I've allowed users to click a link that gets permissions and returns an access token:

index.html

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&response_type=token&scope=email&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html" class="sign_in">Sign In with Facebook</a>
```

index.js

```
function onFacebookLogin(){
  if (localStorage.getItem('accessToken')) {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) { // get all tabs from every window
      for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        if (tabs[i].url.indexOf(successURL) !== -1) {
          // below you get string like this: access_token=...&expires_in=...
          var params = tabs[i].url.split('#')[1];

          // in my extension I have used mootools method: parseQueryString. The following code is just an example ;)
          var accessToken = params.split('&')[0];
          accessToken = accessToken.split('=')[1];
          localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
          chrome.tabs.remove(tabs[i].id);
          console.log(accessToken)
          userSignedIn = true
          findFacebookName();
        }
      }
    });
  }
}

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(onFacebookLogin);
```

^ ALL OF THIS WORKS. Everytime a user "logs in" the localstorage.accessToken is updated. Then, I get to the point where I try to retrieve user data by inspecting the token through the api:

```
var client_token = '{MY_CLIENT_TOKEN(NOT CLIENT_ID}'

var inspectTokenUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=' + 
  localStorage.accessToken + 
  '&access_token=' + 
  client_token

function findFacebookName(){
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", inspectTokenUrl, true);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
    }    
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

But this returns a 190 oauth error. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to request the users email address using the access_token?

Comment: Just wondering, have you looked at [`chrome.identity` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/identity)?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying that route now. I didn't think it would be necessary since I was already receiving the access token.